# Validation Rule to Lock Opp 15 Days After a Quarter Ends

Tags: validation, admin

Title says it all. I'm looking to write a validation rule that effectively prevents non-System Admins ($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator") from changing the Amount, Close Date or creating new Opportunities if 15 days have passed since the the quarter. They should also be able to modify/create Opps in the current quarter.

The only real fields that shouldn't be modified after that date are Stage and Amount. They should be able to change everything else related to an opportunity.

I got this:

```
AND(
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
$Profile.Name <> "API System Administrator", 
$User.FirstName <> "Aram",
OR(
ISNEW(),
ISCHANGED(CloseDate),
ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(StageName) , "Closed Won"),
ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(StageName) , "Closed Lost"),
ISCHANGED(Amount)),
OR(
```

And I'm a little lost after that.

Comment: Seems like you cut off the rule in the middle of your paste job?

Comment: You could create a new `Locked Record Type` and make the layout read only to all profiles except Admins (or grant access to it via permission set) then you'd just need a workflow rule to change Record Type 15 days after quarter ends.

Comment: @AdrianLarson "And I'm a little lost after that."

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions to make your life easier.

First, go to Setup > Develop > Custom Permissions, create a new permission, which you'll reference in the rule. It could be something like "Edit Time-Locked Opps" or whatever you want to call it.

This means you no longer have to check profile names, and you can assign it via permission sets, too. For example, this rule fragment will return true if the user doesn't have the permission, and thus be denied.

```
NOT($Permission.Edit_Time_Locked_Opps)
```

Next, there happens to be a Boolean flag called IsClosed which is set when an opportunity reaches Closed Won or Closed Lost (and any custom closed values you may have). The following fragment returns true when the opportunity is closed, and would prevent edits:

```
IsClosed
```

So, ultimately, your rule should look something like:

```
AND(
  NOT($Permission.Edit_Time_Locked_Opps), 
  IsClosed,
  OR(
    ISCHANGED(Amount), 
    ISCHANGED(CloseDate)
  ),
  OR(
    YEAR(CloseDate) < YEAR(TODAY()-15),
    AND(
      YEAR(CloseDate) = YEAR(TODAY()-15),
      CEILING(MONTH(CloseDate)/4) < CEILING(MONTH(TODAY()-15)/4)
    )
  )
)
```

Working through this, we see if the user has the custom permission we wrote, then we see if the opportunity is closed (won or lost), if our protected fields changed, and then we see if we count back 15 days, is the resulting year greater than the close date's year. Otherwise, we see if the CloseDate is in the current year, *and* the FQ is less than the current FQ (again offset by 15 days).

Comment: The second `AND` clause is just `ISCHANGED`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I meant IsClosed, actually. Thanks for the note.

Comment: I guess if they implement `Custom Fiscal Quarters` they're stuck with `Apex`, eh?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, there's no formula methods I know of that would allow them to know the fiscal quarter of an arbitrary date.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for this - I'll give this a shot tomorrow. I like the idea of using IsClosed - but if we have other stages that are technically closed (e.g. when the donation comes through the door, we technically close the gift, but we use the stage to indicate that it still needs to be won with 'Closed Won - Send Thanks') would that still work?

I didn't know about the custom permission - that's awesome!

Comment: @ZacheryTapp you can adjust this formula to fit your needs. I was just trying to point you in the right direction. If IsClosed won't work, you can certainly specify stage names.

Comment: @sfdcfox much appreciated - I think this is going to work! We are testing now and modifying as needed!

Comment: @sfdcfox our Quarters are typical (starting on 4/1, ending on 3/30 in 3 month intervals), do you think this will work?) I'm still running into snags.

Comment: @ZacheryTapp That's going to be mildly complicated because of leap years, but I think you'd need to change -15 to +75 to be "close enough".